# form autocomplete doesn't getting off

Tags: javascript, html

i have 2 forms, `login` and `add user` when i save my login data it's auto-filling in the second form.

```
<form method="post" action="/admin/addUser" id="add_user"
    autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off">
```

i added a lot of things, i changed the input `name`, `placeholder` and `id`. but still autocomplete working.

even in `js` i used `input.value = ""` , and `form.reset()`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: [How to turn off form autocompletion - Web security | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)

Answer (score 1):

add `autocomplete="off"` for inputs

[read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)